# Why was my question closed as a duplicate of one of my own closed questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

For a while now, I've been trying to post a question on this site about whether Jesus resembled Joseph.  I made three attempts, and they were all closed for different reasons, and so I posted a [Meta question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6377/9438) asking how I could word my question better.  I followed the advice given, and I posted a [fourth version](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/59061/9438) of the question, but then it was closed as a duplicate... of one of my previous attempts to ask the question!

So why was it closed as a duplicate of my own closed question?  Could mods please intervene and reopen it?  Or could I delete my old closed question so my latest version is not a duplicate of it?

Comment: If a question is substantially the same as an older closed question of yours, it's often better to edit it than ask a new one.

Answer (score 4):

I've reopened your most recent question, after considering the following:

- While substantially similar in content, it is narrower than the previously asked question, as it focuses on the appearance of Jesus rather than his genetics

  - It might also be argued that asking for "theologians" instead of "writings" is narrower, but not by much
- Answers to the older question do not deal with the appearance issue

This question still may be too broad for some people's tastes, but I don't think it should be closed as a duplicate of a closed question that does not have the same focus.  And we must remember that *broad* in this context refers to the difficulty in *answering* questions in a reasonable amount of space, not to the breadth of search required to find an answer.

Be aware, as explained in the previous meta post on this topic, that if it turns out that many theologians have addressed this question, further narrowing may be required.